# Report fails when is build in VS but doesn't fail with MSBuild

Tags: reporting-services, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, ssrs-2012

I am trying to create deployment job that would checkout from git and builds all the reports in the solution. If it can't build then I want that job to fail. I've created the simple report with dataset as "select 1 as one" and then added 1 non existing column reference in the report. When I tried to build it with *Visual Studio* it is failing, however it is successfully build with the *MSBuild* ... What can be the issue?

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     [rsFieldReference] The Value expression for the text box ‘one’
>   refers to the field ‘one1’.  Report item expressions can only refer to
>   fields within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate,
>   the specified dataset scope. Letters in the names of fields must use
>   the correct case.     C:\Users\kultasev\Repos\mfi-online-reports\MFI
>   Online Reports\broken_report.rdl  0

Comment: What is your build command line? Are you call MSBuild `15.0` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin` ? If yes, could you please share a sample and some detailed steps to reproduce this issue? We could not give any useful advice before we could reproduce this issue.

Comment: Yes, 15.0. "${bamboo.build.working.directory}\Reports.sln"  /t:Build  /p:Configuration=Debug